# Raspberry PI make a Buzzer Sound using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automation, raspberry-pi, sensors

So i'm trying to make a mini "security system" to check if i left my door open. Basically i have a Raspberry pi with a sensor that check if the door is opened or not if i left it openet a buzzer should make a beep to tell me that i left it open.
I saw the SystemSounds.Beep.Play(); from the System.Media library, but how do i put it in my doorIsOpen method?

```
readonly GpioPin sensDoor = GpioController.GetDefault().OpenPin(6); // Pin door
private Task checkDoor() {
    while (true){ 
        if(sensDoor.Read() == GpioPinValue.High) {
            faglDoor = true;
        }
        else {
            faglDoor = false;
        }
        Task.Delay(-1).Wait(1000);
    }
}

private async Task doorIsOpen()
{
    while (true)
    {
        while (faglDoor)
        {
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the below which has a 5 second delay between each check.

```
readonly GpioPin sensDoor = GpioController.GetDefault().OpenPin(6);
bool IsDoorOpen => sensDoor.Read() == GpioPinValue.High;

private async Task SoundBuzzerIfDoorIsOpen() {
    while(true) {
        while(IsDoorOpen) {
            //Sound Buzzer!
        }
        await Task.Delay(5000);
    }
}
```